# How to show alert dialog for certain list item

Tags: java, android, listview, android-alertdialog, android-listfragment

I'm trying to show an alert dialog whenever I select a particular list item whereas the others would open a new fragment. However after inserting the alreat dialog code, an error is then returned. I don't understand why I'm getting this error when 'intent' has already been initialised. What can be done to resolve this problem?

> Variable 'intent' might not have been initialized

**FragmentFruitChooser**

```
public class FragmentFruitChooser extends ListFragment {

    public FragmentFruitChooser() {
        // Required empty constructor
    }

    /**
     * Whether or not the activity is in two-pane mode, i.e. running on a tablet
     * device.
     */
    public boolean mTwoPane;

    public static FragmentFruitChooser newInstance() {
        return new FragmentFruitChooser();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fruit_chooser, container, false);
        initialize();
        return view;
    }

    List<Fruits> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private void initialize() {
        String[] items = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fruit_names);
        String[] itemDescriptions = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fruit_descriptions);
        for (int n = 0; n < items.length; n++){
            Fruit fruit = new Fruit();
            fruit.setID();
            fruit.setName(items[n]);
            fruit.setDescription(itemDescriptions[n]);
            list.add(fruit);
        }

        FruitListAdapter mAdapter = new FruitListAdapter(list, getActivity());
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = getView();

        mTwoPane = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.detail_container) != null;

        assert v != null;
        ListView lv = (ListView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // get the adapter, then get the name from the adapter at that position
                FruitListAdapter adapter = (FruitListAdapter) parent.getAdapter();

                //reverse the selected state in data model
                for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
                    Fruit fruit = (Fruit)adapter.getItem(i);
                    fruit.setSelected(i == position);
                }
                Fruit fruit = (Fruit)adapter.getItem(position);

                if (!mTwoPane) {

                    Intent intent;
                    if (fruit.getFruit().equals(view.getResources().getString(R.string.apple))) {
                        intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FruitAppleActivity.class);
                    } else if (fruit.getFruit().equals(view.getResources().getString(R.string.orange))) {
                        intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FruitOrangeActivity.class);
                    } else if (fruit.getFruit().equals(view.getResources().getString(R.string.tomato))) {
 AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
            .create();
    ad.setCancelable(false);
    ad.setTitle("Seeded Fruit");
    ad.setMessage("This fruit contains seeds.");
    ad.setButton(context.getString(R.string.ok_text), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
ad.show();
                    } else {
                        intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FruitAppleActivity.class);
                    }
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }

        });

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure how your program works, but in your second `else if` statement, your `intent` is not initialized, yet `startActivity(intent)` is still called:

```
} else if (fruit.getFruit().equals(view.getResources().getString(R.string.tomato))) {
                        AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                                .create();
                        ad.setCancelable(false);
                        ad.setTitle("Seeded Fruit");
                        ad.setMessage("This fruit contains seeds.");
                        ad.setButton(context.getString(R.string.ok_text), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                        ad.show();
                    } else {
                        intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FruitAppleActivity.class);
                    }

                    startActivity(intent);
```

You could do what @seanAshmore answered but it may still result to an NPE. I suggest simply adding a null checker for the intent before actually calling `startActivity()`, like so:

```
if (intent != null) {
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        Log.d(FragmentFruitChooser.class.getSimpleName(), "Intent is null");
                    }
```

You could just put separate `Intent intent = new Intent(...)` for each `if`/`elif`/`else` statement just to be sure. But tis your code, so do as you will.

Comment: What is `getSimpleName` ?

Comment: It simply gets the name of the `Activity`. You can ignore the logs I included.

Answer (score 0):

Just try Intent intent = null; instead of Intent intent; It's hard to tell but I think that should solve your issue –